# How to define schema where value is one or more from a set list of values, similar to multi-select enum

Tags: yaml, openapi

I'm trying to define a schema in openAPI where the value can be one or more from a pre-set list of values.  For example, something like below.  I know it's invalid but, hopefully, it conveys the idea.

```
components:
  schema:
    ingest-rules:
      type: string
      oneOrMoreOf: 
        - "rule1, rule2, rule3 rule4, rule5"
```

Where `ingest-rules` is an array of one or more values from the list of possible values.  It would be similar to an `enum` but where multiple values can be selected.

How can I do this in openAPI v >= 3.0

Thanks.

Comment: Is this schema used as a query parameter or in a request body? If the latter - is the value of `ingest-rules` supposed to be an array of enum, e.g. `"ingest-rules": ["rule2", "rule5"]`? Or it supposed to be a comma-separated string e.g. `"ingest-rules": "rule2, rule5"` where the individual values are predefined?

Comment: @Helen  Thanks for the response.  "ingest-rules"  will be supplied in the requestBody and the value is supposed to be an array of strings.  "ingest-rults" : ["rule1","rule3"]

Comment: See the linked Q&A. (Even though its title says "Swagger 2.0", the answer applies to OpenAPI 3 too.)